# How to Send Python List as Single Email

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, email, html-email

The Amazon scraper code below works 100% as expected. It pulls the Amazon product **Asin** and **Notification Price** from a CSV file **amazon-list-of-asins.csv** and then checks the Amazon website for the respective product and if cheaper sends an price drop email.

It cycles through the CSV file until all products are checked sending an email for every successful price drop found.

## Issue

I need a way to collectively send only **ONE EMAIL** displaying the product(s) and its respective information upon a successful price drop as captured in the list **csv_line_entry**.

I'm not a programmer and have managed to rustle up the code supplied. As you can appreciate several successful price drops will lead to several emails which could result in data usage issues, missing emails, spam, poor user experience, etc.

### amazon-list-of-asins.csv

Asin, Notification Price, Product
B07GS6ZB7T, 50.00, Logitech G502 HERO High Performance Wired Gaming Mouse
B001D7UYBO, 58.00, RØDE PSA1 Swivel Mount Studio Microphone Boom Arm
B0011UB9CQ, 110.00, beyerdynamic DT 990 PRO Studio Headphones

### Python Script

```
import csv
import datetime

import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.header import Header

import requests
from requests.sessions import CaseInsensitiveDict
from requests_html import HTMLSession


# Set User Agent
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/  537.36",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.5",
    "Referer": "http://google.com",
    "DNT": "1",
}

# Start session and create lists
s = HTMLSession()
amz_product_list = []
date = datetime.datetime.today()

def run_scraper():

    # Read CSV File
    with open("amazon-list-of-asins.csv", "r") as f:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(csv_reader)

        # Scrape data
        for csv_line_entry in csv_reader:
            
            r = s.get("https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/" + csv_line_entry[0], headers=headers)
            r.html.render(sleep=1)

            try:
                amz_product_title = r.html.xpath('//*[@id="productTitle"]')[0].text.strip()

                amazon_price = (
                    r.html.xpath('//*[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]')[0]
                    .text.replace("£", "")
                    .replace(",", "")
                    .strip()
                )

            except:
                amazon_price = (
                    r.html.xpath('//*[@id="price_inside_buybox"]')[0]
                    .text.replace("£", "")
                    .replace(",", "")
                    .strip()
                )
            # Check Amazon price is lower than csv notify price
            if (float(amazon_price)) < float(csv_line_entry[1]):
                saving = round(float(csv_line_entry[1]) - float(amazon_price),2)
                print('Amazon Product Title:',amz_product_title)
                print('Amazon Asin:',csv_line_entry[0])
                print('CSV Notify Price:',csv_line_entry[1])
                print('Current Amazon Price:',amazon_price)
                print('   > Saving:',saving)

                #CSV List Format: [csv_line_entry[0], csv_line_entry[1], amz_product_title]
                amz_product_list.append(csv_line_entry)

                #Additional Entries to CSV List Format : [csv_line_entry[0], csv_line_entry[1], amz_product_title, [amazon_price, saving]]
                csv_line_entry.append([amazon_price, saving])

                send_email(amz_product_title, csv_line_entry, amazon_price, saving)


# Define Email Routine
def send_email(amz_product_title, csv_line_entry, amazon_price, saving):

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login('myemailaddress@gmail.com', 'myemailpassword')
  
    frm = "myemailaddress@gmail.com"
    to = "sampleuser@domain.co.uk"
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg.set_charset('utf8')
    msg['FROM'] = frm
    msg['To'] = to

    msg['Subject'] = f'Amazon Saving: {amz_product_title} - £{amazon_price}'

    bodyStr = f'<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>Date & Time Checked: {date.strftime("%a %d %B %Y at %I:%M%p")}<br><br>Link: https://amazon.co.uk/dp/{csv_line_entry[0]}<br>Product Name: {amz_product_title}<br>Asin: {csv_line_entry[0]}<br>Store Price: £{amazon_price}<br>Notification Price: £{csv_line_entry[1]}<br>Total Saving: £{saving}<br></body></html>'

    _attach = MIMEText(bodyStr.encode('utf-8'), 'html', 'UTF-8')        
    msg.attach(_attach)

    server.sendmail(frm, to, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()   

    print("   > EMAIL HAS BEEN SENT\n\n")

run_scraper()
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `send_email` outside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've identified the task at hand: Instead of sending an email for every item, you want to collect these items in a list, then format all these items in a single email body and send that email.

First, create a list to store all your info before the `#scrape data` step

```
all_email_items = []

# Scrape data
for csv_line_entry in csv_reader:
    ...
```

Instead of calling `send_email` for every item, save all that information to a list.

```
if (float(amazon_price)) < float(csv_line_entry[1]):
    # print stuff like you already do
    ...

    #Make a tuple with the relevant info of the current item
    current_item = (amz_product_title, csv_line_entry, amazon_price, saving)
    all_email_items.append(current_item)

    # DON'T CALL send_email() here
    # send_email(amz_product_title, csv_line_entry, amazon_price, saving)
```

Finally, *outside the `for csv_line_entry` loop*, call `send_email` with this list.

```
with open("amazon-list-of-asins.csv", "r") as f:
    ...
    for csv_line_entry in csv_reader
        ...
    
    send_email(all_email_items)
```

Remember to modify `send_email()` to take your list of tuples instead of the regular arguments:

```
def send_email(all_items):
    # Connect to the server, etc.

    bodyStr = f'<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>Date & Time Checked: {date.strftime("%a %d %B %Y at %I:%M%p")}'

    for current_item in all_items:
        # Unpack the tuple into variables you already use
        amz_product_title, csv_line_entry, amazon_price, saving = current_item
        # Add info for current item to bodyStr
        bodyStr = bodyStr + f"<br><br>Link: https://amazon.co.uk/dp/{csv_line_entry[0]}<br>Product Name: {amz_product_title}<br>Asin: {csv_line_entry[0]}<br>Store Price: £{amazon_price}<br>Notification Price: £{csv_line_entry[1]}<br>Total Saving: £{saving}<br>"

    # Close html body
    bodyStr = bodyStr + '</body></html>'


    # Finish sending the email
    ...
```

Comment: Solution works a treat.

How can I amend the Try / Except portion of the script to detect and bypass product(s) that no longer exist on Amazon to avoid the script failing?

Comment: I am not able to provide help beyond the scope of your original question. If you have another question, I encourage you to make a new post, with a [mre] that includes relevant code for that _specific_ question. You should take a look at a tutorial on try-except clauses, and identify what exception is thrown when the script fails. Catch only that exception. While you're at it, redo a tutorial on flow control if you haven't already done one. What flow-control statement allows you to skip the rest of the loop (for example when something fails, you just want to move on to the next item in th loop)